# Systemd: temporary read-write folder in read-only file system

Tags: systemd-unit

I have a system in which a single host can run multiple executions, which are sandboxed using `systemd`.
The execution can specify which folder to be rooted in, e.g.

```
RootDirectory=/var/images/some_root
```

in this path there is a btrfs read-only volume. I would like the execution to have a writable scratch area but I can't create folders in this RO path.

How can I achieve that? Is there a way to mount a temporary RW folder in this file system?